# $__POST[string] to receive a unicode string fails

Tags: php, mysql

Unable to perform the query statement Incorrect string value: `\x96\xBC\x91O\x82\xCD...` for column 'member' at row 1.
Here is the code.

```
    $member=stripslashes($_POST["membername"]);
    $link=mysql_connect(localhost,$username, $password) or die("unable to connect to database ".mysql_error());
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
    mysql_selectdb($database) or die("unable to select db ".mysql_error());

    $query="SELECT*FROM members";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    $rowNum=mysql_num_rows($result)+1;
    $query="INSERT INTO members VALUES ('$rowNum','$member','$memberemail','$memberpass','$memberRegDate','$memberRegDate','$memberIP')";
    mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to perform the query statement. ".mysql_error());
```

EDIT; I already change my DB as this

```
ALTER DATABASE users CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE members CHANGE name name varchar(100) character set utf8;
```

Comment: you want to addslashes not stripslashes if you're putting that into an SQL query. also, use `mysql_real_escape_string`. not sure if that'll fix your problem, but it's a starting point. also, that `$rowNum` better not be your primary key.....just make it an auto-increment and don't bother with this mysql_num_rows non-sense.

Comment: :( Thanks but it's not working

Comment: I can only insert members of Enlish names, but Korean members are failed.

Comment: @OP: unicode characters are always a pain. might have to do with the column character set?

Answer (score 0):

That's not UTF-8. You should be looking at the HTTP headers in the request to see what charset is being used, and convert appropriately.

```
>>> print '\x96\xBC\x91O\x82\xCD...'.decode('cp949')
뼹멟궼...
```

Comment: what is that mean. Can you help for me ? I see sign that I not eligible for the job and likely fire after a week or few weeks.